# How to run a file in Windows like 'bash file' in Linux

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, ping

I have a file containing multiple simple `ping` command like this:

```
ping 1.1.1.1 >> result.txt
ping 1.1.1.2 >> result.txt
ping 1.1.1.3 >> result.txt
...
```

How can I run this file in CMD? In Linux I can run `bash file` so it runs the file, but in Windows I did not find a way to do this.

Using `start ping.txt` runs `ping.txt` file in Notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your file so that it has the `.bat` or `.cmd` suffix (instead of .txt). This appears to be mandatory for the Cmd.exe interpreter to recognize the file as a script.